# Alter content only if it has a child

Tags: html, css

I have some html structure like this:

```
<span class="foo">
  <a href="#" class="bar">text</a>
</span>
```

or

```
<span class="foo">
  text
</span>
```

What I need to do is, replace content of `span.foo` if it hasn't child `a`, but leave it be if  it has.

unfortunately css has no has-child or similar selectors. Here is what I have tried:

```
.foo {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.foo:before {
  content: 'text-replaced';
  visiblity: visible;
  display: inline-block;
}

.foo a {
  margin-left : -10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I used css text replace hack, and tried child `a` to overlap with its parent. the problem is, `a` does not hide above span - they are both displayed, which is ugly. And I don't feel this is the right way to do it - I can't really hardcode the value of `margin-left`, since the length of text inside `a` is variable. -10 is just an example and no matter what number I use it can be longer or shorter than the number actually required. Also, there are many spans with `class="foo"`, and each span may or may not have inner `a` tag - and not all `a` have text of equal length. What is the proper way to do this? I can't use javascript for this kind of problem.

Comment: `display:none;` is better than `visibility:hidden`

Comment: @DominicB-c `display:none;` makes replacement texts to disappear

Comment: @thkang why can't you use JavaScript???

Comment: usage of `<script>` tag is blocked at server level. I can only edit css.

Comment: use it where you use `visibility:hidden;` then use `display:inline, block, or inline-block` where you use `visibility:visible;` if possible. Of course if you use `display:none;` on the parent element it won't display any of the children either. On another note, the CSS for `.foo:before` has a spelling mistake in `visibility`.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is possible in a very satisfactory way.  However, you *might* be able to get away with something like...

```
.foo { visibility: hidden; }
.foo > * { visibility: visible; }
```

It's certainly not ideal, but it will hide foo but not foo's children.

Another lame hack would be to make the element's text transparent, but it's children not:

```
.foo { color:transparent; }
.foo > * { color:red; }
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the first concept worked out, including replacement text: http://jsfiddle.net/EUG8h/. Note that you're going to have to accept less that ideal layout.  You could position the replacement text absolutely to avoid the weird blank whitespace, but then you'll need to ensure that foo is at least as large as the replacement (e.g. using `min-width`).  It's definitely a nasty hack, and it's not going to work in every context.

Comment: thanks. What should I do if I want to make every `foo` has same text?

Comment: Second suggestion is quite far out of the box, good thinking.. But its also worth mentioning that SEs might not like that if you do it with a lot of text.

Comment: I think if you really are going to do something like this, you're obviously grasping at straws and cannot expect the page to be just as usable as a properly built page.  It's a hack- not a great solution.